# How to properly train your Self-Organized Map?

Tags: neural-network, clustering, unsupervised-learning, ann

I recently stumbled upon the Self-Organized Map - an ANN architecture used to cluster high dimensional data - while simultaneously imposing a neighborhood structure on it. It is trained through a competitive learning approach where neurons compete to respond to a given input. The strongest responding neuron / best matching unit (BMU) is rewarded by being moved closer to the given input in the data space, as well as its neighbors. However, within the literature and implementations, I find some deviations in how this training is implemented. Specifically, the influence of the BMU on its neighbors are mitigated using a neighborhood function:

$$\beta_{ij}(t)=exp \bigg({{-d^2}\over{2\sigma^2(t)}} \bigg), \ where \ t=1,2,3...n$$

where $d$ is the distance of the BMU to the input and $\sigma(t)$ is a radius that is decreased during the training. Effectively, resulting in the influence of the readjustment of the BMU on its neighborhood shrinking during training. The difference I find concerns the implementation of the shrinking of $\sigma(t)$. Most explanations and blog posts describe an exponential decrease:

$$\sigma(t) = \sigma_0 \cdot exp \bigg({{-t}\over{\lambda}} \bigg), \ where \ t= 1, 2, 3...n$$

where $\lambda$ is a decay constant that can be tuned arbitrarily. Alternatively, I find that some implementations do not really use this exponential decay, but instead use linear interpolation of the form:

$$\sigma(t)=r(2)+{{n-t}\over{n}} \cdot [r(1)-r(2)]$$

where $n$ is the number of training epochs and $r$ is the radius which is altered depending on the training phase. These implementations further explicitly between a 'rough' training phase where:

$$\vec{r}= \bigg( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0.1 \end{array} \bigg) \cdot max(SOM.dims)$$

with e.g. `SOM.dims=(100,100)` being for a $100x100$ sized SOM, and a 'fine-tuning' training phase where:

$$\vec{r}= \bigg( \begin{array}{c} {0.1 \cdot max(SOM.dims)} \\ 0.1 \end{array} \bigg)$$

My problem is that I do not quite understand why there seems to be this disagreement and what the 'canonical' way of training a SOM is. It certainly makes sense to divide the training into a 'rough' and a 'fine-tuning' phase, but why most newer descriptions neglect this without further discussion and only consider a single training phase with exponential decay is baffling me a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer from Kohonen, inventor of the self-organized map himself:

> "The true mathematical form of σ(t) is not crucial, as long as its
> value is fairly large in the beginning of the process. Say, on the
> order of half of the diameter of the grid, whereafter it is gradually
> reduced to a fraction of it in about 1000 steps."

From: Kohonen, T., 2013. Essentials of the self-organizing map. Neural networks, 37, pp.52-65.